# FlutterFire with Flutter Web (on MacOS). InitializeApp() Not working, returns no errors

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a Flutter web app on a Mac and I want to be able to use Firestore as a backend. The issue is that when I try to initialize firebase I get no errors but it also does not intialize properly. I have followed all the steps with FlutterFire configure and the firebase_options.dart file got generate properly.

I also include the references to both

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
```

Here is the code of my app.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _initialized = false;
  bool _error = false;

  void initializeFlutterFire() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: 'sims',
      options: const FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: 'AIzaSyAjsc1FLog-V4hhhiC27vUaq5TqiIis',
        appId: '1:789704jjjj12939e2de42b466b0cae3',
        messagingSenderId: '789704523738',
        projectId: 'tender-si',
        authDomain: 'tender-si.firebaseapp.com',
        storageBucket: 'marbls-tender-sims.appspot.com',
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeFlutterFire();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(body: SurveyWidget()),
    );
```

Comment: Check [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview#initialization). In the main function of application add this `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );`

Comment: Nice to hear your issue got resolved. It will be helpful for the Community members if you can post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please add these lines in the main function of your app.

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();   
await Firebase.initializeApp(
 options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,   
);
```

*Your initialization in the main function is wrong according to the firebase docs.*

**Check [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#initialization)**