# Firebase.initializeApp returns error despite having latest packages

Tags: flutter, firebase

As per this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72833245/calling-firebase-initializeapp-returns-unable-to-establish-connection-on-chan/72835948), what I need to do is only upgrade all the packages, but all my firebase packages are up to date. So it doesn't solve my problem.

```
flutter pub outdated
Showing outdated packages.
[*] indicates versions that are not the latest available.

Package Name              Current   Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest   

direct dependencies: all up-to-date.
dev_dependencies: all up-to-date.

transitive dependencies:
async                     *2.8.2    *2.8.2      *2.8.2      2.9.0
characters                *1.2.0    *1.2.0      *1.2.0      1.2.1
clock                     *1.1.0    *1.1.0      *1.1.0      1.1.1
fake_async                *1.3.0    *1.3.0      *1.3.0      1.3.1
matcher                   *0.12.11  *0.12.11    *0.12.11    0.12.12
material_color_utilities  *0.1.4    *0.1.4      *0.1.4      0.1.5
meta                      *1.7.0    *1.7.0      *1.7.0      1.8.0
path                      *1.8.1    *1.8.1      *1.8.1      1.8.2
source_span               *1.8.2    *1.8.2      *1.8.2      1.9.0
string_scanner            *1.1.0    *1.1.0      *1.1.0      1.1.1
term_glyph                *1.2.0    *1.2.0      *1.2.0      1.2.1
test_api                  *0.4.9    *0.4.9      *0.4.9      0.4.12
all dependencies are up-to-date.

flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.739], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.16)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.69.0)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

[image]

I have all the things Firebase wants me to do, including the json, gradle plugins, and yaml. But it still won't let me connect.

[image]

Comment: This might help you : https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9028

Comment: Can you show the error you're getting from the console

Comment: to HardikMehta: that link just throws me to the link I have provided above. @Shanu https://ibb.co/dgtXRQs there's no error in console

Comment: You can open this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72833245/calling-firebase-initializeapp-returns-unable-to-establish-connection-on-chan/72835948#72835948

Comment: @HardikMehta yeah I have no firebase dependencies to update because all are already the latest, and you can see I only use firebase core & auth

Comment: You can try once by flutter clean and build again

Comment: @HardikMehta I clean and pub get hours ago, didnt work. I just did it again and still doesnt work. I'm so lost.

Comment: are you using  stable channel for flutter ?

Comment: @HardikMehta yes I'm currently using stable channel

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72845289/fluterfire-with-flutter-web-on-macos-initializeapp-not-working-returns-no/72852181#72852181). Connecting app with firebase using ```flutterfire configure``` command in terminal might solve your problem.

Comment: @BilalSaeed https://ibb.co/zS0bTzn weird, I have flutterfire and firebase already. I even thought of uninstalling my entire local discs